# OptaPlanner SolverManager Bean not being found in Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, optaplanner

I am fairly new to working with Spring and I've come across a problem I cannot seem to resolve.  I am trying to work with a package called [Optaplanner](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.6.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#plannerIntroduction).  In this case I'm more or less following along with a simple course scheduler the video is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqTuRiWGLZQ&list=PLJY69IMbAdq0uKPnjtWXZ2x7KE1eWg3ns) and the part I am working on happens at 51:00.

My problem is, one step of the process requires a dependency injection and when I build/run the Spring application I get the following error:

```
Description:

Field solverManager in com.java.optaplex.resource.MainResource required a bean of type 'org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @javax.inject.Inject()

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have used Gradle to manage my optaplanner package and I can see that the dependency is present (it is an interface called SolverManager).  I cannot figure out why it cannot find/generate the bean however.  I am assuming Spring would generate the bean on the fly much like a JPA repository's bean is created when using the @Autowired decorator.  I have tried copying and pasting the SolverManager code to its own file under my project root and tried a few decorators on it (eg. @Component) in hopes that Spring would detect it, yet it still throws the same error and I am unsure what to do.

I have created a very simple demo app on GitHub [here](https://github.com/kriegsmaschine/optaplanner.simple.demo) that has the error.  The error is in the file **src/main/java/com/java/optaplex/resource/MainResource.java**

Also, in IntelliJ the SolverManager instance **solverManager** (see code below) is highlighted and says:

```
Could not autowire. No beans of 'SolverManager<Test, Long>' type found.
```

MainResource.java:

```java
package com.java.optaplex.resource;

import com.java.optaplex.pojo.Test;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MainResource {

    // THE OFFENDING LINE IS HERE
    @Inject
    SolverManager<Test, Long> solverManager;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public Test test () {
        return new Test("Result message here");
    }

}
```

For clarity, my Test class in the declaration of the Solver manager is:

Test.java

```java
package com.java.optaplex.pojo;

public class Test {

    private String message;

    public Test(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

I realize my example code doesn't actually make use of the SolverManager, I just want the error on build to stop so I can proceed developing this.  I just wanted to provide a very simple case that caused the error.

Lastly, my Gradle dependencies look like this:

build.gradle:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group = 'com.java'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.optaplanner/optaplanner-core
    compile group: 'org.optaplanner', name: 'optaplanner-core', version: '7.36.1.Final'
    compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Source code of that video's quickstart is here: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/development/spring-boot-school-timetabling

Answer (score 1):

To make it work you just need to replace the `@Inject` annotation with `@Autowire`.

From the latest versions of Spring, the best practice is to use constructor dependency injection instead of `@Autowire` (the annotation is not required anymore as Spring will autowire beans automatically.

**Try this:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MainResource {

    // Just the definition here
    private SolverManager<Test, Long> solverManager;

    pubilc MainResource(SolverManager<Test, Long> solverManager) {

     // When Spring will start, the bean will be injected here and become 
     // available in this class
     this.solverManager = solverManager;

    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public Test test () {
         // .....
    }

    // Other controller methods .... 

}
```

I'm using IntelliJ, and it reports the error to me too. But I'm using the same code that I've posted in this answer and it works.

As you stated, the `SolverManager` bean is configured inside the optaplanner artifact, I suspect that the problem here is only the wrong annotation being used.

The IDE error bothers me too! But for the moment it works and I will leave it like this. In case I'll find a solution then I will add it here.

Comment: I have the same problem in Intellij. It's impossible for me to start the application. Is the probleme was solved ? Maybe with optaplanner-spring-boot-starter, optaplanner-spring-boot-autoconfigure ?

Comment: @slim If it's intellij giving you the error, maybe you can try to compile with maven/gradle and see if works without any error. If yes, it means that it's Intellij having problem to recognize which implementation to use, so to avoid the problem go into ```Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Validation```, then momentarily disable ```Spring model```,  and finally build again. If everything works you can keep this configuration, it's just an IDE problem and will not affect the compiled output!

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a API REST of route optimization  with Spring Boot using OptaPlanner. I am just getting into the work with OptaPlanner and at one point I had this same problem. I had 'optaplanner-spring-boot-starter' and I added spring-boot-configuration-processor', with the idea of having the bean creation configuration that allows injecting the SolverManager in my classes, without success. Also I tried to change to other versions of OptaPlanner and without success. Finally I solved the problem adding the configuration that OptaPlanner includes in its code with the class 'RouteOptimizerConfig'. This class creates the bean of the solver, in such a way that already later I could inject it. This problem seems to be related to the fact that at a certain point the OptaPlanner SolverManager is overwritten.

Try this and add this class to your project:

```
@Configuration
class SolverConfig {

    private final SolverFactory<VehicleRoutingSolution> solverFactory;

    SolverConfig (SolverFactory<VehicleRoutingSolution> solverFactory) {
        this.solverFactory = solverFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    Solver<VehicleRoutingSolution> solver() {
        return solverFactory.buildSolver();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this, that is not needed and brittle. Instead, *in your `build.gradle` file, add a dependency to `optaplanner-spring-boot-starter`*, just like in [the sources](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/development/spring-boot-school-timetabling). Then you'll see it complain because `Test` doesn't have a `@PlanningSolution` annotation.

Answer (score -3):

It turns out, after a lot of online searches and digging through the Optaplanner Spring Boot packages the SolverManager bean is not provided for Spring.  It seems the development focuses on the Quarkus framework.

I figured it was a good chance to try out Quarkus and once I made the change my code worked.  There are some good videos on Youtube by the lead developer Geoffrey De Smet on setting up Optaplanner via Quarkus.

Comment: Hi, are you sure about that? Actually I've added the ```optaplanner-spring-boot-starter``` artifact to my spring boot project, and even if the ```SolverManager``` class is reported by my IDE as not found for autowiring, after a quick search I've found that the starter artifact depends on ```optaplanner-spring-boot-autoconfigure```. If you look inside there's a ```OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration``` class, there you will find the ```SolverManager``` Spring Bean. In fact I'm using the solver manager, and ide error aside, it works!

Comment: I forgot... you can find a good introduction video on this page: https://www.optaplanner.org/compatibility/springBoot.html. 
Btw Spring integration is not very well advertised, there's only a little link on the home page :/ You must be lucky to find it!

Comment: We're bringing the spring boot guide and spring boot example home for optaplanner 7.38 - both will be available in the docs and zip download buttons from 7.38 onward.

Comment: OptaPlanner supports Spring Boot 100%. Just like it supports Quarkus 100%. Our compatbility focus is on both.

Comment: But Quarkus is faster and OptaPlanner likes speed as it affects solution quality ;-)

Comment: Hello @GeoffreyDeSmet!  Nice to meet you! Optaplanner is great, I'm building a new project around it. May I suggest to highlight the incompatibility of spring-boot-devtools with it? I got my head fried after a week of intensive checks: the solver was initialized, but it died before feeding all the problem informations into it. I was nearly giving up, then I read in the docs that devtools must be disable. It worked straight away after disabling them! I don't know if this issue happens in every project, it would be cool to print a warning though! Headache saver! :-)

Comment: Good point, I 've created a jira here: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2006

Comment: Nice! There's any community where to discuss about the project, and best practices, or everything is here on stackoverflow?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet can I use optaplanner with spring mvc project

Comment: Yes. But you can only inject SolverManager etc automatically if you use spring boot too. If you don't use spring boot, then you have to call SolverManager.create() yourself.