# Component testing classes that use OptaPlanner

Tags: java, spring-boot, optaplanner

I have a component that, amongst other things, makes use of OptaPlanner. We use junit for component/integration testing and I am having trouble with bean creation when running tests.

When running my test I get the following error...

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager<com.company.uk.product.aepe.service.optaplanner.EngagementSolution, java.util.UUID>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1714)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1270)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1224)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
```

I use optaplanner-spring-boot-starter which normally created a SolveManager bean which is @Autowired'd into my classes, but not when run as a test.

My pom dependencies (sanitized for security reasons)....

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- Actuator Dependencies START -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Actuator Dependencies END -->

  <!-- Spring -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
    <artifactId>optaplanner-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-kafka</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

  ...

  <!-- Test Depemdencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.database-rider</groupId>
    <artifactId>rider-junit5</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
    <artifactId>optaplanner-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Required by Intellij to run Junit 5 tests -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371336/optaplanner-solvermanager-bean-not-being-found-in-spring-application) suggests manually creating the SolverManager bean in a configuration class but also warn off doing this...

What is the 'best' way of ensuring thsi ben is available in my integration tests?

Comment: This is wierd. We should have tests in the autoconfigure module ( https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/main/optaplanner-spring-integration/optaplanner-spring-boot-autoconfigure ) and in optaplanner-quickstarts ( https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/development/technology/java-spring-boot ) that should cover this. Not sure if we do cover this specific case though.

Comment: Maybe your codebase has some other differences causing this bug. Can reproduce the issue in either of those 2 locations in my previous comment and maybe submit a reproducer PR?

Answer (score 0):

When I take the spring school timetabling quickstart of optaplanner-quickstarts and add the `SolverManager` autowired field in this unit test, it works:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = {
        "optaplanner.solver.termination.spent-limit=1h", // Effectively disable this termination in favor of the best-score-limit
        "optaplanner.solver.termination.best-score-limit=0hard/*soft"})
public class TimeTableControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private TimeTableController timeTableController;

    @Autowired
    private SolverManager<TimeTable, Long> solverManager;

    @Test
    @Timeout(600_000)
    public void solveDemoDataUntilFeasible() throws InterruptedException {
        assertNotNull(solverManager);
        ...
    }

}
```

Also, there's test coverage for this in optaplanner repo itself, in `org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OptaPlannerAutoConfigurationTest#singletonSolverFactory`.

**Maybe in your case there's a problem with the generic types?** Try autowiring without the generic types first. Let us know here if that was the problem.